# PYQT5: Window crashes trying to dynamically create image labels

Tags: python, pyqt5

Apologies if the question is confusing, I'm not the best at wording stuff. I'll try to explain further if required.
**Background:** I'm creating a simple image viewer that gives the user the ability to cycle through their library of images. I wanted to give the user the ability to browse through their image library (basically a file browser) so I tried creating a little browser that dynamically added QLabels with pixmap for each image in the library.
**Problem:** First my window crashed without loading any image labels, but since my image library is pretty huge I thought limiting the number would help. The results weren't so different; with the limitation (of only 4 images) the image labels displayed but anytime I try to do anything in the window (resize the window, resize the dock) it crashes. What am I doing wrong here?
**Code:**

```py
import sys
import os
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PIL import ImageQt, Image
import memory_profiler

from DBManager import DBBrowser

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    resize_constant = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = r'Images'
        self.control_modifier = False
        self.resized = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.main_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.main_widget.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        # self.setWindowFlag(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.create_main_window()
        self.viewer()
        self.menubar()
        self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.menu_widget)
        self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.main_window)
        self.main_widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.show()

    def menubar(self):
        self.menu_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.menu_widget.setLayout(qtw.QHBoxLayout())
        self.menu_widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.menu_widget.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.menu_widget.layout().setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft)
        import_btn = qtw.QPushButton('Import', clicked=self.import_database)
        explorer_btn = qtw.QPushButton('Explorer', clicked=self.show_hide_explorer)
        import_btn.setFixedWidth(70)
        explorer_btn.setFixedWidth(70)
        self.menu_widget.layout().addWidget(import_btn)
        self.menu_widget.layout().addWidget(explorer_btn)
        import_btn.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.ClickFocus)
        explorer_btn.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.ClickFocus)

    def create_main_window(self):
        self.main_window = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.dock = Dock('Explorer')
        self.explorer = Explorer()
        self.dock.setWidget(self.explorer)
        self.dock.setTitleBarWidget(qtw.QWidget())
        self.main_window.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.main_window.setFocus()
        self.main_window.addDockWidget(qtc.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

    def viewer(self):
        self.image_handler()
        self.image_label = qtw.QLabel(alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.curr_img_name = self.images[0]
        self.curr_img_org = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, self.curr_img_name))
        self.curr_img_qt = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.curr_img_org)
        self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.curr_img_qt)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)

        self.image_scrollarea = ImageScrollArea(self)
        self.main_window.setCentralWidget(self.image_scrollarea)
        self.image_scrollarea.setWidget(self.image_label)
        self.image_scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.image_scrollarea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(qtc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.image_scrollarea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(qtc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.image_scrollarea.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.NoFocus)

    def image_handler(self):
        self.images = sorted([(int(image.split(os.extsep)[0]), image.split(os.extsep)[1]) for image in os.listdir(self.root)
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.root, image)) and not image.endswith('.csv')])
        self.images = ['.'.join((str(image[0]), image[1])) for image in self.images]

    def resize_image(self):
        self.curr_img = self.curr_img_org.copy()
        self.curr_img_qt = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.curr_img)
        self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.curr_img_qt)
        if self.resized < 0:
            self.curr_img.thumbnail((
                int(self.curr_img_org.width - (abs(self.resized)/100 * self.curr_img_org.width))
                , int(self.curr_img_org.height - (abs(self.resized)/100 * self.curr_img_org.height)))
                , Image.BOX)
            self.curr_img_qt = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.curr_img)
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.curr_img_qt)
        elif self.resized > 0:
            self.curr_img = self.curr_img_org.copy()
            self.curr_img = self.curr_img.resize((
                int((abs(self.resized)/100 * self.curr_img_org.width) + self.curr_img_org.width)
                , int((abs(self.resized)/100 * self.curr_img_org.height) + self.curr_img_org.height))
                , Image.BOX)
            self.curr_img_qt = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.curr_img)
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.curr_img_qt)

    def change_image(self, direction):
        current_index = self.images.index(self.curr_img_name)
        if direction == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            if current_index == 0:
                return
            self.curr_img_name = self.images[current_index-1]
            self.curr_img_org = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, self.curr_img_name))
            self.curr_img_qt = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.curr_img_org)
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.curr_img_qt)
            if self.resized != 0:
                self.resize_image()
            self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)
            self.image_scrollarea.scroll_value = 0
            self.image_scrollarea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.image_scrollarea.scroll_value)
        if direction == qtc.Qt.Key_Right:
            if current_index == len(self.images)-1:
                return
            self.curr_img_name = self.images[current_index+1]
            self.curr_img_org = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, self.curr_img_name))
            self.curr_img_qt = ImageQt.ImageQt(self.curr_img_org)
            self.curr_img_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.curr_img_qt)
            if self.resized != 0:
                self.resize_image()
            self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)
            self.image_scrollarea.scroll_value = 0
            self.image_scrollarea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.image_scrollarea.scroll_value)

    def import_database(self):
        file_location = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Import database', os.path.abspath('.'), 'database files (*.db)')
        self.explorer.set_database_location(file_location[0])
        self.explorer.offset = 0
        gallery_data_dict_list = self.explorer.get_items()
        self.explorer.set_items(gallery_data_dict_list)

    def show_hide_explorer(self):
        if self.dock.isVisible():
            self.dock.hide()
        else:
            self.dock.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            self.change_image(qtc.Qt.Key_Left)
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Right:
            self.change_image(qtc.Qt.Key_Right)
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Up:
            self.image_scrollarea.scroll_(120)
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Down:
            self.image_scrollarea.scroll_(-120)
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Escape:
            if self.dock.isVisible():
                self.dock.hide()
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Control:
            self.control_modifier = True
        if self.control_modifier:
            if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_E:
                self.show_hide_explorer()
    
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Control:
            self.control_modifier = False

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.control_modifier:
            if event.angleDelta().y() == 120:
                self.resized += 10
                if self.resized >= 90: self.resized = 90
                self.resize_image()
                self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)
            elif event.angleDelta().y() == -120:
                self.resized -= 10
                if self.resized <= -90: self.resized = -90
                self.resize_image()
                self.image_label.setPixmap(self.curr_img_pixmap)

class ImageScrollArea(qtw.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_window = main_window
        self.scroll_value = self.verticalScrollBar().minimum()
        self.scroll_constant = 100

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.main_window.control_modifier:
            event.ignore()
        else:
            self.scroll_(event.angleDelta().y())

    def scroll_(self, y):
        if y == -120:
            if self.scroll_value + self.scroll_constant >= self.verticalScrollBar().maximum():
                self.scroll_value = self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
            else:
                self.scroll_value += self.scroll_constant
        elif y == 120:
            if self.scroll_value - self.scroll_constant <= self.verticalScrollBar().minimum():
                self.scroll_value = self.verticalScrollBar().minimum()
            else:
                self.scroll_value -= self.scroll_constant
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.scroll_value)

class Dock(qtw.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

class Explorer(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.database_location = None
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.search_box = qtw.QWidget()
        self.search_box.setFixedHeight(int(0.15*self.height()))
        self.search_box.setLayout(qtw.QFormLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.search_box)
        search_edit = qtw.QLineEdit()
        search_edit.setPlaceholderText('Enter search term(s)...')
        search_bar = qtw.QHBoxLayout()

        filter_options = ['tags', 'people', 'date', 'custom...']
        filter_option_combobox = qtw.QComboBox()
        filter_option_combobox.addItems(filter_options)
        filter_option_combobox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        filter_option_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.custom_filters)

        search_btn = qtw.QPushButton('Search')
        search_bar.addWidget(filter_option_combobox)
        search_bar.addWidget(search_btn)
        self.search_box.layout().addRow(search_edit)
        self.search_box.layout().addRow(search_bar)
        self.browser()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.browser_scrollarea)

    def custom_filters(self, value):
        if value == 'custom...':
            pass

    def browser(self):
        self.browser_scrollarea = qtw.QScrollArea()
        self.browser_scrollarea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(qtc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.browser_scrollarea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(qtc.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

    def get_items(self):
        self.DBB = DBBrowser()
        self.DBB.set_database(database_location=self.database_location)
        self.DBB.set_filters()
        results = self.DBB.sqlite_select(get='*', order_by='date', order_in='ASC', table='Library')
        self.offset += 10
        gallery_data_dict_list = [{
            'location' : result[0],
            'date' : result[1],
            'tags' : result[2]
            } for result in results]
        return gallery_data_dict_list

    def set_items(self, gallery_data_dict_list):
        self.browser_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.browser_widget.setLayout(qtw.QGridLayout())
        key = 0
        for gallery_data_dict in gallery_data_dict_list:
            if key > 3:
                break
            description = qtw.QScrollArea()
            text = qtw.QLabel('texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex')
            description.setWidget(text)
            thumbnail = Image.open(os.path.join(gallery_data_dict['location'], os.listdir(gallery_data_dict['location'])[0]))
            thumbnail.thumbnail((250,250))
            thumbnail = ImageQt.ImageQt(thumbnail)
            self.thumbnail_pixmap = qtg.QPixmap.fromImage(self.thumbnail)
            self.thumb = qtw.QLabel(pixmap=self.thumbnail_pixmap)
            # text.setFixedWidth(int(self.browser_scrollarea.width()*50/100))
            self.browser_widget.layout().addWidget(self.thumb, key, 0)
            self.browser_widget.layout().addWidget(description, key, 1)
            key += 1
        self.browser_scrollarea.setWidget(self.browser_widget)

    def set_database_location(self, location):
        self.database_location = location


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit:**
Following @musicamante's comment, I tried a couple of things to reprex my question and it doesn't seem like anything but a random occurrence with a 99.999% fail rate. I don't say 100% because the same code that crashed a million times worked fine once. I tried stripping the code to nothing but just a `QWidget` with two widgets; a button to load the browser, and the browser.  Nevertheless, it still crashed. I don't know how much more minimal I can go.
Then I realized, I was using `PIL.Image` and `PIL.ImageQt` instead of `QPixmap`. Changing all my images to use qt's pixmap instead fixed the problem, as far as my experience went. I tried using `PIL.Image` for the main viewer and `QPixmap` for the browser but it still crashed.
My question now is, is there a way I can make it work well with PIL? Because, unless I'm missing something, I feel like `PIL.Image` is a lot more feature rich for image manipulation than `QPixmap`. Namely resizing the image (PIL has a ton of algorithms but QPixmap only has `Qt.FastTransformation` and `Qt.SmoothTransformation` as far as I'm aware) and especially the `.copy()` function. Or alternatively, is there some other library?

Comment: Have you tried to run your code using a terminal/prompt and see the possible output and full traceback of the crash? Also, I had to change the behavior of `image_handler` in order to correctly load the list of images: while list comprehensions can be useful, they should be used with care: they should not result in convoluted syntax, as there's very few performance benefit from using them like that, they become very hard to read and make debugging unnecessary complex. That said, once that image listing was changed, I wasn't able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I always run my code via powershell, didn't get any error messages or anything like that. I tried changing the `image_handler` but it did nothing. Honestly I don't see how it would affect the crashing since its not related to the browser (at this point). Could you maybe post here what you changed it to?

Comment: I only changed it in order to comply to an image directory that had more "randomic" names, so I'm not sure if that's your real issue here (but I sincerely doubt it). I suggest you to do some (boring, but almost always helpful) "deep debugging". Start by adding some simple `print` statements here and there, and try/except blocks that at least would narrow the issue at some point. The idea is that you should be able to provide us an actual [minimal *and* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that *always* reproduces the issue for both you and us.

Comment: Hint: consider using a virtual env *and* a virtual machine in order to actually test the MRE. Right now it's still possible that your issue is actually a bug that might only happen under certain situations (OS, OS version, specific Qt/Python/PyQt version or any combination of the above), but *reducing* your code will greatly help us (and you) to find out anything about it.

Comment: The fact that using PIL against QPixmap gives different results might be an important hint. Is it possible that there are some corrupted files in the directory you're trying to browse? PIL should be able to avoid crashes for corrupted files, but, who knows. Maybe it raises an exception under very specific conditions, or it's even possible that there's a bug. Is your PIL updated?

Comment: None of the images are corrupted. My guess why that the resizing done to each thumbnail in `thumbnail.thumbnail((250,250))` was causing the problem due to it being an intensive task or something like that. My PIL version is 8.2.0. Oh yeah just to be clear, its pillow not the old PIL.

Comment: The fact that it's an intensive task should not be a cause for crashes (it *could* if it was related to threading, but this is not the case): the worst that could happen would be that the UI becomes unresponsive until the task is complete.

Comment: That is true. Guess it will remain a mystery...?

Comment: As said, I cannot reproduce the issue, but *you* can. If you have the opportunity, I suggest you to do some debugging using print, logging and more try/except blocks, and by slowly "reducing" your code in order to better track the source of the issue. This could help you to find a possible bug in your implementation *OR* somewhere else in the libraries you're using (or even the OS, who knows?). In any case, it would be extremely helpful: in the first case, to you, in the second, to *lots* of other people too.